# Highcharts duplicating Legend Tags

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an API endpoint returning a string containing a CSV of statuses, and current totals of those statuses.

I am displaying the data in a pie chart with a legend. For the data being returned from the endpoint `STATUS,MESSAGE COUNT,\nDELIVERED,2,\nPENDING,1,\nFAILED,3`.

I am getting a duplicate legend, one set containing the values, the other containing null or undefined values.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p8wa6sor/2/

If someone could help me to understand why my legend is duplicating I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all the last commas in the lines:

```
csv: 'STATUS,MESSAGE COUNT\nDELIVERED,2\nPENDING,1\nFAILED,3',
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1tfLbg0q/